# Unwanted paragraph tags added around checkboxes fieldtype in template

Tags: categories

In my template, I have this code:

```
<dd>{categories backspace="2"}{category_name}, {/categories}{if habitat_category_other} ({habitat_category_other}){/if}</dd>
```

When rendered in the template, it is converted into:

```
<dd><p>Monarch Waystation, National Wildlife Federation, Other</p> (Monarchs Across Georgia)</dd>
```

which gives an odd line break.

How do I get rid of these automatically added paragraph tags? I don't see anything about this in the [documentation for the categories tag pair](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#categories).

Thanks!

**CORRECTION:**

The problem is actually occurring with a different line of code (not the categories tag -- although I will have to check that one now, too, because it's probably also malfunctioning). The offending line is:

```
<dd>{habitat_programs}{if habitat_program_other} ({habitat_program_other}){/if}</dd>
```

where "habitat_programs" is a "Checkboxes" fieldtype. How does this change the answer if it's not the "Categories" tag pair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your field and ensure that **Default Text Formatting** is set to None, this should fix the issue.

Comment: thanks! I just realized that, too. Duh. I should really sit on these questions a little longer before posting them. :)

Comment: Amy, I don't know how many times I've posted a question somewhere to only figure out the answer minutes later. It happens to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Did you change your field type to a checkbox from something else?

Check the Default Text Formatting option in your field options. If it's set to something other than "none" change it to none. If it's on none, change it to something else, then back to none. In either case, a checkbox should show up to update entries with your new choice-- check it. And then click Update.

Everything should be reset to none now, and the tags should be gone.

Answer (score -2):

You could try adding `style="linear"` to your `{categories}` tag.

Per [this](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/categories.html#channel-categories-style) docs entry.